# My internet connection is randomly interrupted when I use a specific service

Tags: networking, 18.04, internet

My internet connection is randomly interrupted when I use a specific service.

Example:

When I use the terminal to download a new package, the connection is broken.

When I use speedtest.net to calculate my internet speed, the connection stops and I get this error: [The image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8TVl.png)

Before update my connection word randomly, after update still stops but only using some services.

Can someone help me?

I'm new in UbuntuOS and this is my version:

Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS

Comment: Look at the logs! `sudo journalctl  -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`.

Comment: What service do you think is causing the interruption?